# How to handle local Postgres data for git version control system in Strapi-Postgres installation

Tags: postgresql, docker, strapi

I installed Strapi using Docker from this [url](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/installation/docker.html) and I used PostgreSQL database.

After successful installation, the folder structure looks like this.

```
/app --- strapi app
/data --- postgres data
docker-compose.yaml
```

My question is how to share the local Postgres data with other team members, for example using Git or whatever.

Comment: What do you mean by sharing db data? There could be many ways to do so.

Comment: I wanted to know if uploading db data to git is good practice or not.

Comment: you know, i have inserted some data in my local and if I want to share it with my friend, which method can i use?
for example, can i use git? or is there a way to share it through docker itself?
or should i include data/ to .gitignore?

Comment: You should make a "seed" script which populates the database. Then your colleagues will be able to create a local DB and run this script.